# passing data to blade with nest()

Tags: php, view, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a post table and a comment table and I want to show a list of my comments. But for showing the title of post for each comment I get thrown this error:

`Trying to get property of non-object (View:\myBlog\app\views\comments\list.blade.php)`

I am really confused about it.

This is my controller:

```
public function listComment()
{
    $comments = Comment::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $this->layout->title = 'Comment Listings';
    $this->layout->main = View::make('admin.index')->nest('content', 'comments.list', compact('comments'));
}
```

This is my comments/list.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{$comment->commenter}}}</td>
        <td>{{{$comment->email}}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{$comment->post->title}}</td>-->

        <td>
            {{Form::open(['route'=>['comment.update',$comment->id]])}}
            {{Form::select('status',['yes'=>'Yes','no'=>'No'],$comment->approved,['onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
            {{Form::close()}}
        </td>
        <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('comment.delete','Delete',$comment->id)}}</td>
        <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('comment.show','Quick View',$comment->id,['data-reveal-id'=>'comment-show','data-reveal-ajax'=>'true'])}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
{{$comments->links()}}
```

What is my wrong with passing data to `comments/list.blade.php`?

Comment: I think you should try renaming your `views/comments.list.blade.php` to `views/comments/list.blade.php`. Blade probably recognizes your dot  in 'comments.list' as a folder.

Comment: @Unnawut: thanks for reply but it just was my address in this question .it knows the path just cant access the field and I dont know why .